# Poisson-Bracket representation of the Poincaré group and symmetries of dynamical systems

Tags: symmetry, hamiltonian-formalism, poincare-symmetry, poisson-brackets

In canonical formalism we know that a symmetry for the dynamical system can be expressed by $\{H,f\}=0$, where $H$ is the hamiltonian of the system and $f$ is the smooth function associated to the infinitesimal generator of a transformation (because you can think about the infinitesimal generator of a transformation as the hamiltonian vector field generated by a smooth function). For example, the smooth function associated to space translations $T_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ is $p_i$, the generalized momenta in the i-th direction.

But if you look at the Poisson bracket relation characteristics of the Poincaré group, you have that $\{H,p_i\}=0$. Does this mean that every physical system always has translation as a symmetry?

Comment: No: it only means that Poincaré-invariant sysmtems have translations as a symmetry. Not every system is Poincaré-invariant. A necessary condition is, of course, translation symmetry. The case of boosts is arguably [much more interesting](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/287887/84967).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform It is correct to say then that a Poincaré-invariant system closes the Poincaré algebra?

Comment: Not sure what "closes" means in this context, I would say "realizes" instead. But yes, a Poincaré-invariant system is one with: 1) a set of continuous symmetries that 2) close into a group which 3) is isomorphic to the Poincaré group. In more mundane terms, it is a system that is invariant under both Lorentz and translations. And Lorentz means invariant under rotations and boosts.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform My only doubt is about the boosts, because in the Poincaré algebra we have $\{H,K_i\}=-p_i\neq 0$ but this means that boosts are not a symmetry for my system with hamiltonian $H$, even if with this relation I can realize the Poincaré algebra

Comment: Your claim is actually wrong. Symmetry does not require $\{f,H\}=0$, but rather $\{f,H\}+\partial_t f=0$. And boosts do satisfy that, cf. the post linked in my very first comment.